# Slack command does not trigger App script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, http-post, slack, slack-commands

I have created a slack app and granted it the needed permissions, then I added a slack command that is connected to a simple google app script that adds info to a google sheet and installed the app on my slack workspace.
But when I try to use the command, I always get /register failed with the error "dispatch_failed" and from the logs, I can tell that the request is not reaching the script.

The app script

```js
function doPost(request){
  console.log("GOT here");
  var params = request.parameter;
  var text = params.text; //the options provided after the command as a single string
  //visit https://api.slack.com/slash-commands/#app_command_handling for available payload sent by slack
  var names = text.split(" ");
  var firstName = names[0];
  var lastName = names[1];
  
  addRow(firstName, lastName);//call function to add row as declared below
  
  var response = {    
    "response_type": "ephemeral",
    "text": firstName + " " + lastName +" has been added to our records",
  };
  //finally we return the reponse back to slack
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function addRow(firstName, lastName) {
   // more info https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.appendRow([firstName, lastName]);//adds a new row to the sheet
}
```

[image]

Can you please help to find why it is not working as expected?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the detailed setting of your deployed Web Apps?

Comment: @Tanaike I have added the deployment settings in the post.
I have tried something, that I copied the same script to another project on my personal email and shared it with anyone ((without within ...)) and it worked!
It does not work when I use the other email and share the webapp with within the email domain, Even though I use slack with the same email of the domain that shared with the web app

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I noticed that your "Who has access" is "Anyone within ###". I thought that this might be related to the reason for your issue. In your situation, I'm worried that the request from Slack might not be able to be done. If you want to confirm this, please ask the administrator of your organization. For example, when you simply test your script, how about using your personal Gmail account? In that case, the Web Apps can be accessed from Slack.

Comment: As the additional information, when you can select `Anyone, even anonymous` and/or `Anyone` as "Who has access", please test it. If you can do this, it might be able to be accessed from Slack to your Web Apps. But I'm not sure whether you can select it because this depends on the setting by the administorator. I apologize for this.

Comment: You are requesting the web app URL without any kind of authentication, but the web app can only be accessed by accounts from a certain domain, so it does require authentication. As Tanaike said, deploy the web app to be accessed by `Anyone` or `Anyone, even anonymous`, making it publicly accessible. Is it a feasible solution for you?